# Agarose gel electrophoresis - wrong running conditions?

Tags: gel-electrophoresis

Please have a look at the electrophoregram. 
The DNA ladder used is GeneRuler 50bp (loaded according to the instructions), size of the gel is 6*7cm, lane width is 4mm, agarose percentage is 1%, TBE buffer. The power supply is Consort EV243. Running conditions were: 120V, 200mA, 45W, 40'.

What went wrong? The ladder is very far from the lane, and the sample bands look fuzzy. During run voltage remained constant (120 W), while current and power were  slightly changing (56mA and 7W ~in the middle of the run). Should I change running conditions? And/or make a fresh TBE running buffer?

[image: Electrophoregram]

Comment: How long did you let it run? I think time is a factor here. I would cut the time down by 15 mins.

Comment: @GabrielFair 40’ = 40 minutes.